# Android: Issues with setting up USB debugging for HTC Sensation

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to be able to debug my applications straight to my phone. What I have done so far is:

- Downloaded the USB driver software from the HTC website for my Sensation
- Tried to install said driver software. I double click on the item in the Firefox downloads list; the installer runs and finishes.
- Download the Google USB Driver in Eclipse
- Enabled USB debugging on my phone
- Declared my application as debuggable (i.e. android:debuggable="true")

After doing all of this, I still can't debug straight to my phone. Any ideas as to what I might be missing?

Comment: if you want to debug your app with `break point`, some devices may be dont support.

Comment: @DilSe: Yep. I was able to copy stuff to the SD card

Comment: While you run the app is running in emulator?

Comment: When I click Run, it automatically starts up the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then Right click on your project.
Select DebugAS
Click on Debug Configuration
Click on Target in window and unselect all the AVD Name and then click on Debug.

Try this  must solve your issues.

Comment: I just tried this and my device isn't showing up in the list of running devices.

Comment: It turns out that HTC Sync was what was needed to make things work. But your answer did point me in the right direction, so I'm picking it. :D

Answer (score 1):

To debug or test your code on your HTC sensation Android phone, install the HTC Sync on your computer from http://www.htc.com/www/support/ (Windows) after mounting the SD card and then enable debugging mode from developer options, also don't forget to enable "Allow installations from unknown sources" (Settings->security->Unknown sources). Then everything works fine!